# How do I proceed with pricing after calculating local vol volatilities?

Tags: option-pricing, local-volatility

What are the next steps for pricing under the local volatility formula? It feels like I'm missing the trick (as I only see the numerical methods used to obtain prices after calculating local vol).

I.e. I understand the *derivation* of the local volatility formula below but not the *application*:

$$ \sigma_{local}(T,K)=\sqrt{2\frac{\frac{\partial C}{\partial T}+rK\frac{\partial C}{\partial K}}{K^2\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial K^2}}}$$

As I understand the following are the (basic) pricing steps:

1. obtain the $ \sigma_{local}(T,K) $ function for all values of $S$ and $T$ (with adequate granularity) using the finite difference approximations based on observed option prices.
   When pricing by:

- **Monte Carlo** use equation $dS_t=\mu(t)S_tdt+\sigma_{local}(t,S_t)S_tdW_t$ with appropriate value of $\sigma_{local}(t,S_t)$ for steps at different times $t$ and prices $S$ instead of flat $\sigma$ like in BS
- **FDM** use $\sigma_{local}(t,S_t)$ for gridpoints at different times $t$ and prices $S$ instead of flat $\sigma$ (e.g. in the explicit scheme like here: https://www.quantstart.com/articles/C-Explicit-Euler-Finite-Difference-Method-for-Black-Scholes)

Are these steps correct (subject to adding more sophistication to each of these approximations)?